# phablet-tools : 依赖: click 但无法安装它

Tags: android

follow the torturial(http://www.ubuntu.org.cn/phone/install)
error happened in step 1

```
root@Y:/etc/apt# sudo apt-get install phablet-tools android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot  
正在读取软件包列表... 完成  
正在分析软件包的依赖关系树         
正在读取状态信息... 完成         
有一些软件包无法被安装。如果您用的是 unstable 发行版，这也许是  
因为系统无法达到您要求的状态造成的。该版本中可能会有一些您需要的软件  
包尚未被创建或是它们已被从新到(Incoming)目录移出。  
下列信息可能会对解决问题有所帮助：  

下列软件包有未满足的依赖关系：  
 phablet-tools : 依赖: click 但无法安装它  
E: 无法修正错误，因为您要求某些软件包保持现状，就是它们破坏了软件包间的依赖关系。  
root@Y:/etc/apt#
```

From Oli as a rough translation:

```
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree package
Reading state information ... Done
Some packages could not be installed. If you are using the unstable distribution, this may be
Because the system is unable to meet the requirements of the state of your cause. There may be some software you need this release
Package has not yet been created or they have been new to (Incoming) directory out.
The following information may be helpful to solve the problem:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  phablet-tools: dependency: click but unable to install it
E: Can not fix the error, because you ask some packages to keep the status quo, that they destroyed the dependencies between packages
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a primarily English site, so if possible could you post the error message as it appears in English? If not, I fear it is unlikely that we will be able to help you much.

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` when you are already root? That's redundant.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the problem is [the `click` package is only included in the repos for Saucy and Trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=click&searchon=names&section=all) and that you're using something older. You have a few options:

- The easiest solution is to upgrade to Saucy.
- You could [download the debs from Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/+source/click) and install them manually to fulfil the dependency. I've honestly no idea how well this would work because I don't know how Click interacts with the rest of the system.
- You could build it for yourself [from the source](https://launchpad.net/click).

Comment: Adding to this, one could do the command-line approach (assuming a 64 bit system): `wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/c/click/click_0.4.11_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i click_0.4.11_amd64.deb`

Comment: Yeah, there are a few other related packages too that might also be useful (or required) so I think the cleanest solution is going to involve an upgrade.